# (De-)Serializing Spring Boot ConfigurationProperties with Jackson

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

My spring Boot application uses a class annotated with `@Configuration` and `@ConfigurationProperties`:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyConfigurationProperties {

    @Value("${timeout}")
    private int defaultTimeout;
}
```

Now I'd like to read and update these configuration properties using a (private) REST interface, so I created the following controller.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "config")
public class ConfigController {

    final MyConfigurationProperties myConfig;

    public ConfigController(MyConfigurationProperties myConfig) {
        this.myConfig = myConfig;
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<MyConfigurationProperties> get() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(myConfig);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as I get the following exception when calling the endpoint:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)`

The JSON response even contains "strange" properties when disabling `FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS`:

[image: JSON response example]

How would I be able to (de-)serialize this configuration class using Jackson?

When removing the annotations `@Configuration` and `@ConfigurationProperties` for testing purposes, the serialization works just fine. So it seems to have to do something with the class being a bean?

Comment: does that class have getters and setters ? i do see annotation but make sure lombok is enabled in your project

Comment: Yes, getters and setters are available. Lombok is enabled. Serialization is working fine if the `@Configuration` annotations are removed but this won't fulfil my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing things: configuration properties and autowiring a value. If you want to have a POJO as a configuration property class, drop the `@Value` annotation. You can also drop `@Configuration` annotation if you add `@EnableConfigurationProperties` to your main class (this way all `@ConfigurationProperties` classes will be automatically detected). If a problem persists, please update the question and show us how the properties prefixed with 'my' look like.